# 'Model' conflicts with the declaration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to access model in jquery.But it shows the error,

> > CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model'

My Model

```
 public class News
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewsArea { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model NMS.Mod.Entities.DTO.News



      <script type="text/javascript">
       if ('@Model.Name.Contains("ABC")')
         {
           alert("ABC");
         }
       </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your whole view ?

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are using something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.YourProperty)` (capital `M`) - in which case it should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourProperty)`. As noted above, you need to show the complete view